# How to get from sketch to design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, design-principles

Despite me asking it because of A concrete problem of mine I think the overall problem can be applied more generally and may help beginners to semi-beginners.
The question goes like this:

If you know how your design is going to look like and you already have sketches and the general idea, how do you go about it in programs like Illustrator? How do can you predict what shapes and tools to use to make it look a certain way? Are you able to make it look like hand written despite done with vector tools? Can you draw it in directly?

Overall I would love to hear your thought process in doing your work. From Idea to Final Design.

If you like a practical example, you can use this :3
[image: PIC]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really very broad, but I'll give an answer anyway. There are several ways you could approach recreating a signature.

1. Scan it, place in Illustrator, and use Live Trace. Oh and don't draw your sketch on lined paper! White paper only!
2. Scan it, place in Illustrator, lock the layer, add a new layer, create your artwork on top by tracing over it manually with the Pen tool. Delete the raster layer when finished.
3. Avoid the sketching stage entirely, and draw it directly with the brush tool, and applying a variable width stroke.
4. Use a Wacom graphics tablet and stylus as an input device, which is certainly easier to use than a mouse, especially for writing by hand, or drawing. Plus a Wacom is pressure sensitive, and with Illustrator you can use the pressure sensitivity to control the width of strokes.

Now if you are looking for specific tutorials, there are quite literally thousands available online, if you search for them. I always recommend beginners start with tutorials, and work their way through the basics first.

Comment: A fine general answer, but in my humble opinion avoid Live Trace like the plague. Has anyone ever seen reasonable results form it?! :) Concentrate on the pen tool. You will get the knack of it in the end, and never look back.

Comment: Absolutely right, but it really depends on the quality of the artwork and the scan. Garbage in, garbage out, so to speak.

Comment: @mayersdesign Yes, sometimes you get good results. Depends n what you do and what your source is.

Comment: Cool, I made the sketch with a WACOM Tablet in Onenote. Is there a way to just copy&paste or do I need to scan it? (I can deactivate the lines)

Comment: If you have a Wacom tablet, you can use it directly in Illustrator. There's no need to scan it, or use other software. Just write it in Illustrator!

Comment: Thanks, figured it out. Seems like my tablet bugged and that is the reason I could not draw directly in Illustrator. Thanks, now everything is working!